# Does the sentence "Taking a short view By Jonathan Berman" sound well in the following context?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I'm writing a presentation about the systems of the body, and I'm talking about these issues very shortly. So, my question is if I can write in the first page of the presentation the following sentence:

```
                               Body systems 

                            Taking a short view 

                             By Jonathan Berman
```

I don't know how it sounds like, because I'm not English native speaker, and I would like to present a suitable title, that doesn't sound weird.

Comment: using brief instead of short would be more appropriate

Comment: Do you mean "taking a brief view with / by Jonathan"?

Comment: yes.  "taking a brief view by Jonathan"

Comment: *brief* is also a verb. Body Systems **briefed** by Jonathan

Comment: By the way, you would use "does" instead of "do" in your question because "the sentence" is singular.

Comment: "Short view" is often a synonym of "inability to see far" or "refusal to see the whole picture".  "A brief overview" is probably what you want.

Comment: This question isn't about a sentence.  It's about a two-part title and a byline.  The two-part style seems appropriate, but I have to recommend placing a colon at the end of the first part.

Comment: Short vs. brief depends, I think, on exactly the sort of presentation. Highly technical might be better with brief (it sounds high-brow), but short is probably more engaging if this is addressing the general public. Neither is in any way wrong, I would say.

Comment: FYI, the title of this question, "sound well" should probably have "well" replaced with "good/acceptable/appropriate". Maybe someone else can give a more technical explanation, but "well" usually only refers to some sort of physical performance: "he did well on the test", "the car ran well", "we think the presentation went well", etc.. It usually doesn't refer to subjective topics, like how food tastes ("it tastes good" vs. "it tastes well").